# Pacemaker and Stonith : passive node won't bring up resources

Tags: cluster, ipmi, pacemaker

I'm working with Pacemaker and Stonith for High-Availability with a 2-node cluster (nodes called here A and B). Both nodes have one IPMI as fence device.

The deal is :

- A is currently running resources
- B is in passive mode

Then I plug off the supply of the A node. So every eth interfaces AND IPMI on A are unavailable. Here comes the trick : B tries unsuccessfully to bring A down, cause A's IPMI is unreachable. When N attempts have been done, B gives up and brings itself to "Block" state (called IDLE in the log file).

Here is my question : how can I force B to bring back resources even if Stonith A fails ?

I understand the consequences (concurrent writes, etc ...), but I rather like these compared to a service unavailable at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have the problem described already:

> B tries unsuccessfully to bring A down, cause A's IPMI is unreachable.

Unless B can complete a successful fence operation, it will hang to avoid split-brain scenario. You can mitigate this by configuring secondary fencing mechanism.